# How to set textcolor dynamically in label inside listview in xamarin forms

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, themes

How to set textcolor dynamically to a label inside in a listview .Need to set text color of the label in the entire app based on the users choice. I already declared styles in App.Xaml. Have a class style, declared color for the app in that. Currently taking color from there .But I need to set 2 colors for a label and select color based on the users choice.

App.XAML

```
   <ResourceDictionary>
        <Style TargetType="Label" x:Key="label_style">
            <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="{x:Static local:Style.LabelLightColor}"></Setter>
        </Style>
    </ResourceDictionary>
```

Style class

```
 public class Style
{

    public static Color LabelLightColor = Color.Red;
 }
```

MainPage.xaml

```
 <Label Text="Welcome to Xamarin.Forms!"
         Style="{DynamicResource label_style}"/>
```

Comment: remove the key from the style declare and the style would apply to all the label in the app and also remove Style from label on your main page <Label Text="Welcome to Xamarin.Forms!"
       />

Comment: <Style TargetType="Label" >
            <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="{x:Static local:Style.LabelLightColor}"></Setter>
        </Style>

Comment: Hi, I have updated an answer, you could have a look when you have time. If the reply is helpful, please do not forget to accept it as answer( click the ✔ in the upper left corner of this answer) and vote it up, it will help others who have similar issue.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to use **Style** to achieve that, there is a **[Dynamic Styles in Xamarin.Forms](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/styles/xaml/dynamic)** to do.

Create the Style in **ContentPage.Resources**:

```
<ContentPage.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="labelGreenStyle" TargetType="Label">
        <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="Green" />
    </Style>
    <Style x:Key="labelRedStyle" TargetType="Label">
        <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="Red" />
    </Style>
</ContentPage.Resources>
```

The code of **Label** as follows:

```
<Label Text="{Binding eMail}" Style="{DynamicResource myLabelStyle}" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"></Label>
<Label Text="{Binding eMail}" Style="{DynamicResource myLabelStyle}" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"></Label>
```

Then can modify the `TextColor` by Button click event as follows:

```
private void RedButton_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Resources["myLabelStyle"] = Resources["labelRedStyle"];
}

private void GreenButton_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Resources["myLabelStyle"] = Resources["labelGreenStyle"];
}
```

The effect:

[image]

In addition, you also could bind a **Color Value** for `TextColor` property in Xaml, then modify the data of model can change the `TextColor` dynamically.

For example , the **Contacts.cs** items as follow:

```
public class Contacts: INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public string eMail { get; set; }

    private Color myColor;
    public Color MyColor
    {
        set
        {
            if (myColor != value)
            {
                myColor = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("MyColor");
            }
        }
        get
        {
            return myColor;
        }
    }


    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

}
```

Then we can create **ContactViewModel.cs**:

```
public class ContactViewModel
{
    public List<Contacts> MyList { set; get; }
    public ContactViewModel()
    {
        MyList = new List<Contacts>();
        MyList.Add(new Contacts() { Address = "1", eMail = "1111@11.com", MyColor = Color.Red });
        MyList.Add(new Contacts() { Address = "2", eMail = "2222@22.com" });
        MyList.Add(new Contacts() { Address = "3", eMail = "3333@33.com" });
        MyList.Add(new Contacts() { Address = "4", eMail = "4444@44.com" });
        MyList.Add(new Contacts() { Address = "5", eMail = "5555@55.com" });

    }
}
```

**XAML** code as follows:

```
<ListView x:Name="MyListView"
            ItemsSource="{Binding MyList}"
            ItemSelected="MyListView_ItemSelected">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ViewCell>
                        <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal"
                                        VerticalOptions="Center">
                            <Label Text="Hello World" TextColor="{Binding MyColor}"
                                    HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand"></Label>
                            <Label Text="{Binding Address}"
                                    HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"></Label>
                            <Label Text="{Binding eMail}"
                                    HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"></Label>
                        </StackLayout>
            </ViewCell>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

I will modify the text color after select item as the example.

```
public partial class PageListView : ContentPage
{

    public PageListView()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        BindingContext = new ContactViewModel();
    }
  
    private void MyListView_ItemSelected(object sender, SelectedItemChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var item = e.SelectedItem as Contacts;
        item.MyColor = Color.Green;
    }
}
```

The effect:

[image]